# Convert my server video url to rtsp url

Tags: android, rtsp, android-videoview

I am playing video from a server url in `VideoView` in Android. But I read that for playing video from server RTSP is necessary. I did not understand how I can convert my video in RTSP?

Comment: it is not necessary. RTSP is a protocol, like HTTP. You need RTSP server

Comment: @VladMatvienko I make my custom player that is play video from my server Url. It is working fine but sometime when i position of seek bar manual it give error video can't play. How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Ask a question about that. Current question does not relate to your new question. Don't forget to attach the logs